# How to get full response instead of just body using await in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, request, async-await, response, request-promise

I'm using the request-promise-native library, and I'm trying to get the full response from a request instead of just body because there is something in the response header I need to log. I know usually to accomplish that task you would do something like so:

`request.post(opts).then(function (response) {
     //response
 }).catch(function (err) {
     // error
 })`

but I'm using Async/await, so my code looks something like this: `const data = await request.post(opts)`, however, this will only return the body of the response I want access to the header as well, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `resolveWithFullResponse` option with Request and that solved the issue. e.g `resolveWithFullResponse: true`

Answer (score 1):

You can use fetch :

```
 const response = await fetch(URL, {
                                   method: 'POST',
                                   headers: {
                                             'Accept': 'application/json',
                                             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                            }
                             })
```

And then :

```
const fromHeader = JSON.parse(response.headers.get('header-name'))
```

Comment: where do I import fetch from? also, is there no way to do it with request.post?

Comment: Maybe there is, not that I'm aware of.. I'm normally using fetch. You don't need to import it from anywhere .

Comment: so if i'm guessing to get the body from that i'll just do JSON.parse(response.body)

Comment: To get the body you need to use `await  response.json()` @BroulayeDoumbia

Comment: I see, I'll try that and see

Comment: `fetch` worked kinda, but I had to change a lot of my code to accommodate that, I just added `resolveWithFullResponse: true` option to request and it fixed my issue. thx for the help tho.